# "It was the first time I did" vs. "it was the first time had done"

Tags: past-perfect, past-simple

Could you tell me if there is any difference between the following sentences?

> I saw that movie last year, and actually **it was the first time I saw** it.
>
> I saw that movie last year, and actually **it was the first time I had seen** it.

Comment: 1) I don't see any difference in meaning between the alternatives within the question. 2) The title to the question might be improved if you quoted those passages instead of the words you do place in quotation marks; the part following vs. contains no grammatical subject. 3) I don't know why this question was downvoted, but that's my chronic condition.

Comment: If there's a slight difference, I think _the first time I saw it_ implies that you have seen it a number of times since.  _The first time I had seen it_ could suggest that it's a classic film and it's mildly surprising that you hadn't seen it before.

Comment: @Chaim I agree that any difference is slight and may even be unintentional. The question seems reasonable for this site so I support your “chronic condition” and voted the question up again.